# C++ traits for non-template function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

At the definition of a function template, the instantiations of template parameters are in general unknown. Type traits can be used to obtain some information at compile-time. For example, here is a trivial application of `is_pointer`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T p) { cout << is_pointer<T>::value << endl; }
```

My question is this: Is there ever a situation, in a *non-template* function, where traits-like, compile-time functions could provide useful information?

Comment: What would you want to know about a type you already know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Max value of an int on your platform is "
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << "\n";
}
```

This is the first example that came to mind.  I'm sure there are many others.  More generally, it allows compile-time "lookup" keyed on type.  Obviously, in a non-template situation, the same could be achieved with macro definitions (`INT_MAX`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Oli, that is an interesting answer. I will test your patience by saying that I'm actually looking for a situation where, given a function, with a parameter type lexically denoted "X", there is something about "X" which will vary, depending on the argument provided. (I think the answer is probably no, but I'm not absolutely sure.)

Comment: Ok, I give in. My question was poorly worded. What you provide is "useful information". In the sense of my previous comment then, I think the answer is no.

Comment: @user643722: Oh sorry, I missed your previous comment.  I think you're asking "can traits do anything based on run-time information?", in which case the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Unless to inspect compile time info about basic type, like the max and min for integral types or whatever.

The real benefit for type traits is to aid template meta programming, either by addding control flow with sfinae or to produce better error when an incorrect type is used.